# Is 'Where is this Used Button' reliable?

Tags: process-builder, fields, platform-bug

I've got a field which is definitely being referenced in a visualforce page (in an inputfield, and being written to from there) as well as being part of a criteria in a process builder, but when I click on the 'Where is this used' button it displays nothing.

I've tried log in-out, clear browser cache. I'm admin and should have access to everything. Other fields on the object *appear* to have 'where is this used' list populated correctly.

In docs it says it should display visualforce page references and process builder (criteria) reference.

Is this a known issue? Can I rely on this button to give all references to a field? Are there any work-arounds to find all in-org references to a field?

Field details:

Field is long text area 32,000 length. The vf page just has inputField with the field reference as value - it is writing to the field correctly, so reference must be working.

```
<apex:inputfield value="{!current.Personal_Bio__c}" id="bio" styleclass="form-control" />
```

There is another long text area field on the same object on the same page which does have the reference appearing in 'where is this used'.

Comment: Can you add your vf page code as well where you are saying your field is part of? What kind of field it is?

Comment: [Docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_references.htm&type=5) clearly says it will find the reference.

Comment: Vlad from Salesforce is here :) When you say "button ... displays nothing", do you mean literally no references, or you just don't see that particular reference to the visualforce component you created? Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirGerasimov Hi - no references.

Comment: Hi @eaeaoo, can you file a case? We have a similar bug on our plate right now where the button is not able to process some private joint reports properly and fails to produce any results, but we would need to investigate further to see if your issues is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the high-risk high-reward solution and tried to delete the field.

It came up with an error message telling me where the field was being used - I'm not sure if this is advisable in all circumstances, but it worked for me.

This must be a bug of some kind that is preventing the 'where is this used' list from populating for this particular field.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the reliability of the button, but I do know of a (partial) workaround.
If you're using the metadata API to write code on your computer and then save it to Salesforce, you can search for the field in your entire project. (In most developer environments this is done with Ctrl+Shift+F).
Of course, this will only search in objects you have downloaded. But most objects can be downloaded these days.

Answer (score 1):

This Happy Soup app is a good alternative - you just go to the website, login with your Salesforce details and it pulls the meta data in so you can search for fields.  I'm a Salesforce Admin not a developer and it makes it much easier for me to trace back where a field is used: https://happysoup.io/usage